# The requested route [/echo/cat] has not been mapped in Spark

Tags: spark-java

I'm new to learn Spark with Java. I try to work on Get request.

When I work the code, localhost:4567 isn't an issue.I have a problem about mapping in Spark.

Here is the code below.

```
Spark.get(new Route("/echo/:thing") {
            @Override
            public Object handle(final Request request, final Response response) {
                return request.params(":thing");
            }
        });
```

The code throws

404 Not found

The requested route [/echo/cat] has not been mapped in Spark.

How can I fix it . Thank you.

Comment: `Spark.get` supposed to receive as arguments *at least* a path and a Route. Your `get` receives just a Route somehow. Are you sure this code is compiling? What Spark version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by SHG, since [Spark 2.0.0 (May 2014)](http://sparkjava.com/news#spark-20-released), the `get` method requires at least 2 parameters: a path and a callback.
Therefore your code is no more valid and you are encouraged to upgrade to Spark 2 because Spark 1 is no more updated.

With Spark 2, your code becomes:

```
Spark.get("/echo/:thing", new Route() {
    @Override
    public Object handle(final Request request, final Response response) {
        return request.params(":thing");
    }
});
```

or even simpler with Java 8 lambda notation:

```
Spark.get("/echo/:thing", (req, res) -> {
    return req.params(":thing");
});
```